# Guaranteed 'if' statement elimination by using templates

Tags: c++, if-statement, templates, compiler-optimization

I am wondering if it can be guaranteed (by the compiler's implementation) that certain 'if' statements are never going to be implemented in binary code, i.e., no jumps for some given 'if' statements are ever going to be used in the binary code.

This can be motivated with examples, but let me be brief. Assume you have a class like this one:

```
template<bool N = true>
class A {
    public:
        // ...

        void f() {
            // do some work
            if (N) {
                // do some optional work
            }
            // do more work
        }

        // ...
};
```

Is the 'if' statement inside the function `f` ever going to be implemented by a modern compiler when class `A` is instantiated as `A<false>`? By "implemented" I mean if branching (or jump) instructions are going to be produced.

It seems to me that the answer is negative, i.e., the compiler will remove it (probably because it does not make much sense to implement `if (false) { .. }`). But is this guaranteed to happen  in *all* compilers? How do I know if *a* compiler does this kind of optimization? Is that 'if' statement going to be removed only when optimization flags (e.g., `-O1` or higher in `g++`) are passed to the compiler? In other words, is it also removed when there is no optimization at all?

Comment: FWIW, `if constexpr` guarantees this, which will work here since `N` is a constant expression.

Comment: "*How do I know if a compiler does this kind of optimization?*" If you truly need to care *this much* about the micro-performance of a piece of code, then you should constantly be observing the assembly output by your compiler(s) of choice.

Comment: @NathanOliver that is interesting, I'll check it.

Comment: @NicolBolas, sure thing. I'm very interested in getting rid of every if I can in my code, but sometimes they are necessary (or I can't see how to get rid of them). I'm mostly interested about the trend among compilers in optimizing out 'if's (as long as it can be done, of course).

Comment: @Lluís if you know an if statement is never going to be excuted the best thing to do is remove it complete, if you dont need it, dont use it, most effecient way...

Comment: @Lluís: "*I'm very interested in getting rid of every if I can in my code*" That's called "premature optimization". Stop doing it. Unless you have a *specific* performance need from a specific piece of code, these kinds of things ought to be beneath your notice. 80% of your runtime code will come from 20% of your code, so spending a lot of time on the non-critical 80% of your code is a waste of your time. Write, profile, optimize, *in that order*.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are right. This is an advice one can't be given too many times. I worded that badly. Not *every* but *most*, especially those inside loops and functions that are called countless times (I know by profiling). I have these classes with if's inside its functions that are never used in some cases. I realized after profiling that I could remove them for those cases and improve the efficiency of some algorithms. I did not do it with templates, but with an extra parameter in the functions of the class. The lowest speedup I got is 1.8x. I simply wondered if templates could do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
if constexpr (condition)
```

syntax would be an interesting solution, without a template

Comment: *"without a template"* - The guarantees `if constexpr` gives about discarding statements are **only** in templates.